# QML TapHandler on top of child elements (ListView)

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

ListView steals taps from TapHandler regardless of declaration order. That is, the Rectangle, which is declared first, responds to a click, but not the ListView, which also lies below the TapHandler.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: tap.pressed ? "#6698D9" : "white"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            Layout.preferredHeight: text.height
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "transparent"
            border {
                color: "blue"
                width: 3
            }

            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 24
                color: "red"
                text: "some text"
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: seriesView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            orientation: ListView.Vertical
            spacing: 5
            clip: true
            model: ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: seriesView.width
                height: childText.height
                color: "transparent"
                border {
                    color: "blue"
                    width: 3
                }

                Text {
                    id: childText
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    font.pointSize: 24
                    color: "green"
                    text: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }

    TapHandler {
        id: tap
        onTapped: console.log("Tapped root")
    }
}
```

[image]

I also do not understand why the tap on the free area is not caught. It's about TapHandler. Not MouseArea.

[image]

I would like the TapHandler to catch clicks within the parent element (highlighted in red).

[image]

repo link: https://github.com/conelov/SO_qml_TapHandler_question

Comment: Why must you use `TapHandler`? Didn't you indicate that the `MouseArea` works? Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, because you use `Layout.fillHeight: true` the `ListView` extends to the entire bottom. This means the `ListView` covers both the area covered by your delegates and the blank area.

```
        ListView {
            id: seriesView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
```

As you observed, because `ListView` gets the mouse events the `TapHandler` will not get any.

Two things you can do to get the `ListView` to cede mouse events to the `TapHandler`. (1) you can declare additional `TapHandler`s in the `ListView` delegates. (2) you can reduce blank space of the `ListView`.

```
       Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            ListView {
                id: seriesView
                width: parent.width
                height: Math.min(parent.height, childrenRect.height)
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    // ...
                    TapHandler { }
                }  
            }
      }
```

Here's a working example that implements the above.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    id: root
    
    background: Rectangle {
        color: tap.pressed ? "#6698D9" : "white"
    }
    
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        Rectangle {
            Layout.preferredHeight: text.height
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "transparent"
            border {
                color: "blue"
                width: 3
            }
            
            Text {
                id: text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pointSize: 24
                color: "red"
                text: "some text"
            }
        }
        
        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            ListView {
                id: seriesView
                width: parent.width
                height: Math.min(parent.height, childrenRect.height)
                orientation: ListView.Vertical
                spacing: 5
                clip: true
                model: ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: seriesView.width
                    height: childText.height
                    color: "transparent"
                    border {
                        color: "blue"
                        width: 3
                    }
                    
                    Text {
                        id: childText
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        font.pointSize: 24
                        color: "green"
                        text: modelData
                    }

                    TapHandler {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    TapHandler {
        id: tap
        onTapped: console.log("Tapped root")
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

With all this effort to make `TapHandler` work this way, it might be easier to simply use `MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent}` instead. It wasn't clear why you needed to use `TapHandler`?